# Environment Variables are in a char* how to get it to a std::string

Tags: c++, winapi, cstring

I am retrieving the environment variables in win32 using `GetEnvironmentStrings()`. It returns a `char*`.

I want to search this string(char pointer) for a specific environmental variable (yes I know I can use `GetEnvironmentVariable()` but I am doing it this way because I also want to print all the environment variables on the console aswell - I am just fiddling around).

So I thought I would convert the `char*` to an std::string & use find on it (I know I can also use a c_string find function but I am more concerned about trying to copy a `char*` into a `std::string`). But the following code seems to not copy all of the `char*` into the `std::string` (it makes me think there is a `\0` character in the `char*` but its not actually the end).

```
char* a = GetEnvironmentStrings();
string b = string(a, sizeof(a));
printf( "%s", b.c_str() );  // prints =::=
```

Is there a way to copy a `char*` into a `std::string` (I know I can use `strcpy()` to copy a `const char*` into a string but not a `char*`).

Comment: Who the f* tries to close this off as an exact duplicate? It's a completely different question!

Comment: @Xeo: Well, no, it is not... The `getenv`/`GetEnvironmentVariable` function used is different but the result is the same... All the OP's got to do is replace the `getenv` call with a `GetEnvironmentVariable` call.

Comment: @rubenvb: Except GetEnvironmentStrings() returns a dodgy format, which the OP requires *specific* help with. You cannot just replace `getenv` with `GetEnvironmentStrings()`.

Comment: Problem is not exactly the same. After all he is not trying to learn how to do it, he is after why it happened that way.

Comment: Woops, my apologies, I'm not awake enough to use my "close" votes.

Comment: @rubenvb: You know, *even if* the OP was asking about `GetEnvironmentVariable`, it does actually have a different interface to `getenv` and I wouldn't call it a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not want to use `sizeof()` in this context- you can just pass the value into the constructor. `char*` trivially becomes `const char*` and you don't want to use `strcpy` or `printf` either.

That's for conventional C-strings- however `GetEnvironmentStrings()` returns a bit of a strange format and you will probably need to insert it manually.

```
const char* a = GetEnvironmentStrings();
int prev = 0;
std::vector<std::string> env_strings;
for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
    if (a[i] == '\0') {
        env_strings.push_back(std::string(a + prev, a + i));
        prev = i;
        if (a[i + 1] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < env_strings.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << env_strings[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks I understand, so it must be true, that char* of environ variables is full of \0 chars. I take your approach but I think instead of iterating over every char I will use the c string function strtok to split it at the \0 characters

Comment: @Mack: You can't do that. `GetEnvironmentStrings` returns memory which you are not allowed to write over, and `strtok` is not thread-safe, and it's hideously unsafe anyway. Use a C++ approach.

Comment: @Mack: Not to forget, `strtok` is a hideously *wrong* thing in and of itself. It's a full-blown singleton state machine.

Comment: @Mack: Oh, and I don't think it's possible to get `strtok` to not stop at the first `\0`, and wait for a double `\0`. All the C-string libraries will expect `\0` as a terminator- that's why you need custom parse code.

Comment: Does it work if there are not environment variables: ie "\0" is returned.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(a)` in what you have above will return the size of `char*`, i.e. a pointer (32 or 64bits usually). You were looking for function `strlen` there. And it's not actually required at all:

```
std::string b(a);
```

should be enough to get the first environment variable pair.

Comment: Check the documentation for GetEnvironmentStrings- it won't be enough.

Comment: thanks but I have tried that & it still prints out =::= it makes me think that there is a \0 character at the end of each Environment variable which is why I am getting that little bit

Comment: @Mack, yes, the above will only catch the first one, sorry I forgot that environment block layout.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `GetEnvironmentStrings()` points to memory containing all environment strings. Similar to the solution of Puppy it will be put into a vector of string, where each string contains just one environment variable (`"key=value"`)

```
std::vector<std::string> env_strings;
LPTCH a = GetEnvironmentStrings();
```

As example we will have 2 environment variables defined:

```
"A=ABC"
"X=XYZ"
```

`LPTCH a` will be:

```
A=ABC\0X=XYZ\0\0
```

Each variable is `'\0'` - terminated and finally the complete environment string (`a`) will be terminated with an additional `'\0'`.

`strlen` will return the size to the first occurrence of the termination character `'\0'`. The last string will always be empty.

```
while ((std::size_t len = strlen(a)) > 0)
{
    env_strings.push_back(std::string(a, len));
    a += len + 1;
}
```

## Multi-byte character

For multi-byte characters it will work as well:

```
LPTCH a = GetEnvironmentStrings();
std::vector<std::wstring> env_strings;

while ((std::size_t len = wcslen(a)) > 0)
{
    env_strings.push_back(std::wstring(a, len));
    a += len + 1;
}

FreeEnvironmentStrings(a);
```

Comment: You can use `std::string_view` to avoid allocating+copying the strings just to process them (e.g. looking for a specific variable). But copy what you need to save before calling FreeEnvironmentStrings().

Comment: Note, the pointer `a` returned from `GetEnvironmentStrings` had been modified before passed to `FreeEnvironmentStrings`...

Answer (score 0):

Does the following causes any problems?

```
char* a = GetEnvironmentStrings();
string b;
b=a;
printf( "%s", b.c_str() );
```

Comment: well I got more into the std::string, it prints out: =::=::\ now

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
string b = string(a, sizeof(a));
```

you are getting the size of a, which is a pointer and is probably 4. So you will get the first 4 characters. I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, but you should be able just to say:

```
string b( a );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* a = ...;
string str(a);
string b;
b = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the Windows API [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187.aspx) function. So, test the result against nullptr and perform simple assignment:

```
char* env = ::GetEnvironmentStrings();
if (0 != env)
{
   std::string senv = env;
   // use senv to find variables
}
else
{
   // report problem or ignore
}
```